# vba - action triggered after selection in validation list

Tags: excel, vba

Given a dropdown list with values coming from a different sheet, I would like to fill some cells with values related to the selected line:

So that when I select the param name:
[image]

Coming from another sheet:

[image]

I fill the cell Value and others with value related to the selected line.

I properly made the list and tried to add the WorksheetChange:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim param As String
param = Target.value

Set lineBool = .Find(param, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not lineBool Is Nothing Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lineBool, 2) = Worksheets("DEF_BOOLEAN").Cells(lineBool, 6).value
End If


End Sub
```

But I don't get exactly where the above code should be placed (I tried in the sheet file but gives me a reference error when I run it) and neither if it actually can work.

Comment: you have to place it in the sheet code. The one you have your Validation list on.

Comment: I tried but it seems like the function is never called

Comment: See the Answer, Also you need to explain a bit more about from where you want to copy the data and where you want to paste it. It's not clear in the code

Answer (score 0):

**You have to add the Code in Sheet Code**

[image]

**And change the code to this:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 10)) Is Nothing Then

Dim param As String
Dim lineBool As Range

param = Target.Value
Set lineBool = Find(param, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not lineBool Is Nothing Then
    Cells(lineBool.Row, 2).Value = Worksheets("DEF_BOOLEAN").Cells(lineBool.Row, 6).Value
End If

End If


End Sub
```

You were not calling the Intersect. You would want to activate this code only when something in Row A changes.

Comment: it returns a Compilation error: function not defined

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Okay ..After pasting the Code, try changing anything in cell A3

Comment: that's what I tried, with no changes. While I get the error If I run it from the vb window

Comment: @AndreaGiordano , you cannot run this from vb Window, if you are able to run it from there that means you have not pasted the code correctly in the correct sheet. Otherwise it will not do anything if you try to run it from vbwindow. because it's `WorkSheet_Change` event, it will only run when you change something in the Range A2:A-

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheet_Change` event is, as the name implies an event, triggered by a change on a worksheet. To make you code work you have to put it in the code pane of the worksheet of your validation list.
You can manually call the Sub, like any other sub, from another procedure present in the same code module as the event procedure;  to do so you need to supply a `Range` object to the `Worksheet_Change` procedure.

I suggest a slight adjustment to your code however:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim param As String
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    param = Target.value
    Set lineBool = Worksheets("DEF_BOOLEAN").UsedRange.Find(param, LookIn:=xlValues) ' My guess
    If Not lineBool Is Nothing Then
        Me.Cells(lineBool.Row, 2) = Worksheets("DEF_BOOLEAN").Cells(lineBool.Row, 6).Value
    End If
End Sub
```